# MySql phpmyadmin tables to Laravel migrations files

Tags: laravel, migrate

I've DB in phpmyadmin with many tables in it.
I want to auto generate those tables into seperate laravel migration files.
Does anyone know of such a possibility?

Comment: Do you want to migrate your tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install package for that https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator

Answer (score 0):

This way your migrations table will be separated for each database.

Use the `--database` parameter with the `migrate` command and store the migrations for each database in separate directories.

You could have separate directories in `app/database/migrations` for each of your database (for example : `db1` and `db2`) and store the appropriate migrations in each directory. Then you could run the migrations like this:

```
artisan migrate --database="db1" --path="app/database/migrations/db1"
artisan migrate --database="db2" --path="app/database/migrations/db2"
```

If you want to go the extra mile and automate the process you could create your custom command that will run all the migrations at once. You can create the command like this:

```
artisan command:make MigrateAllCommand --command=migrate:all
```

You can check the [Laravel Command Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/commands) for more info.